# Psych::SyntaxError: (<unknown>): found character that cannot start any token while scanning for the next token at line 34 column 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I am geeting Below Error when trying to find the particular record and I have also used `serialize :value`

```
2.0.0-p598 :003 > Model.find(123)

from /home/linux3/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p598/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb:205:in `parse'
    from /home/linux3/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p598/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb:205:in `parse_stream'
    from /home/linux3/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p598/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb:153:in `parse'
    from /home/linux3/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p598/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb:129:in `load'
    from /home/linux3/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@tod/gems/activerecord-4.1.9/lib/active_record/coders/yaml_column.rb:26:in `load'
    from /home/linux3/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@tod/gems/activerecord-4.1.9/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/serialization.rb:105:in `unserialize'
    from /home/linux3/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@tod/gems/activerecord-4.1.9/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/serialization.rb:96:in `unserialized_value'
    from /home/linux3/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@tod/gems/activerecord-4.1.9/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/serialization.rb:79:in `type_cast'
    from /home/linux3/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@tod/gems/activerecord-4.1.9/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/read.rb:128:in `block in read_attribute'
    from /home/linux3/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@tod/gems/activerecord-4.1.9/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/read.rb:111:in `fetch'
    from /home/linux3/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@tod/gems/activerecord-4.1.9/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/read.rb:111:in `read_attribute'
    from /home/linux3/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@tod/gems/activerecord-4.1.9/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:314:in `attribute_for_inspect'
    from /home/linux3/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@tod/gems/activerecord-4.1.9/lib/active_record/core.rb:357:in `block in inspect'
    from /home/linux3/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@tod/gems/activerecord-4.1.9/lib/active_record/core.rb:355:in `collect'
    from /home/linux3/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@tod/gems/activerecord-4.1.9/lib/active_record/core.rb:355:in `inspect'
    from /home/linux3/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@tod/gems/railties-4.1.9/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:90:in `start'
    from /home/linux3/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@tod/gems/railties-4.1.9/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    from /home/linux3/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@tod/gems/railties-4.1.9/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:69:in `console'
    from /home/linux3/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@tod/gems/railties-4.1.9/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
    from /home/linux3/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@tod/gems/railties-4.1.9/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:8:in `require'
```

Comment: What's the raw data in that serialized attribute for that object?

Comment: That doesn't look like valid yaml - how was the data inserted?

Comment: Actually I am upgrading the rails application from rails2.3.5 to rails 4 and this data already inserted before upgrade.

Comment: @frederick is there any alternate solution?

Comment: In your database console, `SELECT * FROM models WHERE id = 123` and identify the raw data from the column that is serialized and add to your question. I know it hasn't changed between upgrades, but it will still help track down the problem.